# How to return a WM_COPYDATA message instantly and also call a function?

Tags: c++, winapi

How to return a response when receiving a `WM_COPYDATA` message 'instantly' and also call a function?

I tried to use `chrono` but the app that sent the message only receive a response after the `sendCommand` function has been executed.

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

void sendCommand(std::chrono::seconds delay, std::string cmd)
{
     std::this_thread::sleep_for( delay );
     std::cout << "\nThe waited command is =" << cmd;
}


switch (msg)
{
    case WM_COPYDATA:
    {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"\nWM_COPYDATA!");
        PCOPYDATASTRUCT pcds = reinterpret_cast<PCOPYDATASTRUCT>(lParam);
        //....

        auto s1 = std::async(std::launch::async, sendCommand, std::chrono::seconds(5), "Command1");

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code example, you are not doing anything with `pcds` (which points to the data provided by `WM_COPYDATA`). Should the function `sendCommand` have access to this data? The answer to your question depends very heavily on this. In my answer, I am making the assumption that you don't want to discard the data passed by `WM_COPYDATA`, but that you want to have access to that data when the function `sendCommand` gets called. This makes it necessary to copy that data, because the original pointer is only valid inside the `WM_COPYDATA` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a lambda function (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and looks like this:

With std::thread:

```
  std::thread t([]
  {
    sendCommand(std::chrono::seconds(5), "Command1");
  });
```

With std::async
Solution with shared future, by capturing it the lifetime of the future is extended to the life time of the lambda.
If you're on windows/msvc this has the small benefit of using a thread from a threadpool. Otherwise just use the thread solution.

```
    #include <memory> 
    
    auto ft = std::make_shared<std::future<void>>();
    *ft = std::async(std::launch::async, [ft]    
    {
        sendCommand(std::chrono::seconds(5), "Command1");
    });
```

Comment: The same thing, the sending app only receives the message after the function has been executed.

Comment: Oh yes, the nasty details  : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

If the std::future obtained from std::async is not moved from or bound to a reference, the destructor of the std::future will block at the end of the full expression until the asynchronous operation completes, essentially making code such as the following synchronous. You could also use std::thread... lemme check

Comment: Ok I've had this issue myself once.. and came up with a solution, I put it in the answer.
But it might be more understandable for you if you just just std::thread. Example updated

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind blocking the thread that received the `WM_COPYDATA`, you could simply use [`ReplyMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-replymessage):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void sendCommand(std::chrono::seconds delay, std::string cmd)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( delay );
    std::cout << "\nThe waited command is =" << cmd;
} 

switch (msg)
{
    case WM_COPYDATA:
    {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"WM_COPYDATA!");
        PCOPYDATASTRUCT pcds = reinterpret_cast<PCOPYDATASTRUCT>(lParam);
        //...

        ReplyMessage(1);
        sendCommand(std::chrono::seconds(5), "Command1");

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I am assuming that you don't want to discard the data sent by `WM_COPYDATA`, but that you want the function that you are calling to have access to this data.

It is not necessary to use multi-threading to solve this problem, if you allow the [`WM_COPYDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-copydata) handler to copy the data before returning.

What the `WM_COPYDATA` handler could do is

1. dynamically allocate memory for copying the data,
2. then actually copy the data,
3. then post a user-defined message containg a pointer to the copied data to the message queue using [`PostMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea),
4. then return immediately, without calling the function to process the data.

When handling the user-defined message later in the thread's message loop, the handler to the user-defined message could then call the function to process the data and then, after the function returns, free the dynamically allocated data.

It is necessary to copy the data inside the `WM_COPYDATA` handler, because the pointer to the data becomes invalid as soon as the handler returns.

Comment: There are any cons of using multi-threading?

Comment: @Razec: Yes, there are significant cons to using multi-threading, such as the need to use [thread synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)#Thread_or_process_synchronization) to prevent [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when accessing shared variables. However, using multi-threading can also have advantages, such as the ability to use more than one CPU at a time. It all depends on the situation.

Comment: @Razec: In your case, if all you want your thread to do is sleep for a certain number of seconds, print a message and exit, then using multi-threading is probably ok. However, more complex stuff, especially if it involves sharing data with other threads, is not so easy. Therefore, you should generally not use multi-threading unless you have a special reason to do so.